# Is there a noun for a person who helps tourists?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word (if exists) that means a person who helps and guides tourists in her/his city.

As in

> The __________ told them about local customs and showed them the finest sights in the city.

Comment: A local *guide*?

Comment: Is any form of payment included?  Is it a profession or just an occasional voluntary work?

Comment: @DanBron  Yes local

Comment: @Centaurus Occasional voluntary work

Comment: An amateur touristic guide.

Comment: In the US usually "tour guide" is used.  Or just "guide".

Comment: Depending on exact context, [docent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/docent) may work as well.

Comment: This question should be re-opened as @JEL has added the required example sentence. I don't have to reputation, could others complete this process?

Answer (score 2):

Several exist, of more or less currency. One is mentioned in an earlier answer: 'cicerone' occurs 170 times in the [*NOW Corpus*](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/), and so is second only to 'tourist guide' and 'tour guide'.

Others are

1. 'sightsman', no occurrences.
2. 'xenagogue' (obsolete), occurs once.
3. 'lionizer', no occurrences.
4. 'provodnik', occurs twice.
5. 'tourist guide', occurs 451 times.
6. 'tour guide', occurs 4174 times.

The frequency for 'tourist guide' and 'tour guide' in the sense you mention is somewhat less than the raw number of occurrences shown, because some of those occurrences are references to sources of information other than people. As a rough gauge of the error rate, two of the fifty most recent occurrences in the corpus refer to information.

Comment: _Xenagogue_ is an awesome word and I intend to work it into my daily vocabulary.  _Cicerone_ would be good, but my first connection when I heard it was [Madonna Ciccone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna_(entertainer)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed -- [cicerone](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cicerone).

For example, from Dictionary.com:

> a person who conducts sightseers; guide.